# self-signed certificate error with NodeJS request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, ssl, request

I am using the [request](https://github.com/request/request) library for NodeJS in a proxy server.

I have it working fine, but I want to change the proxy so that instead of forwarding HTTP requests to an HTTP address, inbound HTTP requests get forwarded to an **HTTPS** address.

But when I run and attempt to use the proxy I get the following error:

> ```
> stream.js:74
>       throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
>       ^
>
> Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
> ```

I followed online instructions to create a key, crt and a fake certificate authority (linked to in the code), but the error above indicates it still isn't working.

Am I doing anything obviously wrong?

My code looks like this:

```
var certFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.CA-signed.crt');
var keyFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.CA.key');
var ca = path.resolve(__dirname, 'demoCA/newcerts/1234567890.pem');

app.use(function(req, res) {
    var rewriter = request({
        url: rewrite(req.url),
        qs: req.query,
        cert: fs.readFileSync(certFile),
        key: fs.readFileSync(keyFile),
        passphrase: 'foobar',
        agentOptions: {
            ca: ca
        }
    });
    req.pipe(rewriter);
    rewriter.pipe(res);
});

function rewrite(url) {
    console.log('url: ', url)
    var rewritten = 'https://example.com:9000'.concat(trimQuery(url));
    console.log('rewritten: ', rewritten);
    return rewritten;
}
```